# PHPMailer, SMTP error on godaddy hosting

Tags: smtp, phpmailer

I know this question has been answered many times but godaddy made some configuration changes at the beginning of 2018 and I can't make my web form to work.

I'm trying to send email with PHPMailer through contact form from a webpage hosted on godaddy.

I'm using the gmail SMTP configuration:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->Username = "sender@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "************";
$mail->AddReplyTo(sender@gmail.com);
$mail->SetFrom(sender@gmail.com);
$mail->From = sender@gmail.com;
$mail->FromName = Sender Name;
$mail->AddAddress(username@domain.com);
$mail->Subject = utf8_encode("=?UTF-8?B?" . base64_encode("Email text") . "?=");
$mail->MsgHTML("Message");
$mail->WordWrap = 450;
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Send();
```

This is the error I receive:

```
SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection refused (111) 2018-04-12 17:08:56   SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting 
Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

I already try web searching for the issue, check the PHPMailer Troubleshooting and change the configuration parameters but still no able to make it work. Also calling godaddy is not useful, they said that it's a code error.

Same code works on localhost and other hosting.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure it's a GoDaddy issue and not a gmail (auth) one? Appears as though the connection via the SMTP is what's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

Just need to change $mail->IsSMTP(); for $mail->IsMail();

Comment: While it makes your code run, that isn't actually fixing the problem at all. For example you will not be able to use your gmail address as the from address as it will be considered a forgery and you will fail SPF checks and messages will be bounced or spam filtered. When you switch to `isMail()`, you are sending through GoDaddy's servers, not gmail's, exactly as the troubleshooting guide says.

Answer (score 0):

For use mailer you have to create email in goddday

> focus on  **$mail->IsMail();**

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->IsMail();        // Set mailer to use  NONE SMTP
$mail->Host = 'mail.vedantaxyz.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = false;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'manoj@vedantaxyz.com';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'password';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 25;        

$mail->setFrom($adminemail, $appname);
$mail->addAddress($reciveremail, 'Hello - Forgot Password');     // Add a recipient

$mail->addReplyTo($adminemail, $appname);
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
$mail->Subject = 'Hello- Forgot Your Password';
$body = "<b>Body here</>";
$mail->Body    = $body;
$mail->AltBody = '';

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo $mail->ErrorInfo;
    echo (json_encode(['status'=>true,'msg'=>'Mail sent to your email']));
} else {
    echo (json_encode(['status'=>false,'msg'=>'Mail not sent']));
}
```